Differential equation particular integral
I was trying to solve the differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + 2\frac{dx}{dt} + 5x = 4e^{-t}(\cos(2t)+\sin(2t))$$
when i came across an issue. First, i considered the auxiliary equation ${\lambda}^2 + 2{\lambda} + 5 = 0$, getting $\lambda = -1 \pm 2i$, hence the complementary function is $e^{-t}(A\cos(2t)+B\sin(2t)).$
My issue comes when deciding on a particular integral. Both $x = e^{-t}({\alpha}\cos(2t)+{\beta}\sin(2t))$ and $x = te^{-t}({\alpha}\cos(2t)+{\beta}\sin(2t)) + e^{-t}(\gamma\cos(2t)+{\delta}\sin(2t))$ fail.
When plugging these into the original differential equation, I end up with too few simultaneous equations to solve.
I have no idea what to try for the particular integral for this differential equation. If anyone has any idea for what could work, or knows of an easier way to solve the equation than considering the auxiliary equation, please let me know.
p.s. I know the formatting on this post is bad, I have very little experience in using LaTex, so tips on that are appreciated too

a solution of the form $x(t)=A_0te^{-t}\cos(2t)+B_0te^{-t}\sin(2t)$ should work

Regarding LaTeX, you don't need to write greek letters between curly braces, i.e. you can write \gamma instead of {\gamma} and it's better to use \sin and \cos instead of sin and cos

It is useless to consider terms like $e^{-t}(\alpha\cos(2t) + \beta\sin(2t))$ for the particular solutions, even if they imitate the nonhomogeneous term of the right-hand side, because they coincide with the homogeneous solution, so that they will be annihilated by the differential operator of the left-hand side.
The next "natural" ansatz for the particular solution is given by $x_p = te^{-t}(\alpha\cos(2t) + \beta\sin(2t))$, as you expected. I guess you made an error in your computations, because it doesn't fail; indeed, one has $\ddot{x}_p + 2 \dot{x}_p + 5x_p = 4te^{-t}(\alpha\cos(2t) + \beta\sin(2t))$, hence $\alpha = \beta = 1$ by comparison.

Yep, I made an error in computation. I left a bracket open ended and hence forgot to do a few multiplications. What i was trying did work. Thank you for your help though

$$
x^{\prime\prime}+2x^{\prime}+5x=4e^{-t}\left( \cos 2t+\sin 2t \right) 
$$
For the particular solution,we can use differential series method(DSM),
set $y_p$ is  particular solution.
These formulas that we will use,as follow,
$$
\frac{1}{f(D)}e^{\lambda x}v(x)=e^{\lambda x}\frac{1}{f(D+\lambda)}v(x) \\
cosx=\Re{e^{ix}} \\
sinx=\Im{e^{ix}} \\
\frac{1}{D+k}\cdot 1=\frac{1}{k}(k\ne 0) \\
\Im{iz}=\Re{z}\\
\Re{iz}=- \Im{z}\\
$$
so,for $y_p$
$$
y_p=I=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}4e^{-t}\left( \cos 2t+\sin 2t \right) 
\\
=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}4e^{-t}\left( \Re e^{2it}+\Im e^{2it} \right) 
\\
=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}4e^{-t}\cdot \Re e^{2it}+\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}4e^{-t}\Im e^{2it}
\\
=4\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}\Re e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}+4\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}\Im e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}
\\
=4\Re \frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}+4\Im \frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}
$$
we can set $J$,
$$
J=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t} \\\\
I=4\Re J+4\Im J 
$$
for J,
$$
J=\frac{1}{D^2+2D+5}e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}
\\
=e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}\frac{1}{\left( D+2i-1 \right) ^2+2\left( D+2i-1 \right) +5}\cdot 1
\\
=e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}\frac{1}{D^2+4iD}\cdot 1
\\
=e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1
\\
=e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}\frac{1}{D}\cdot \frac{1}{D+4i}\cdot 1
\\
=e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}t\cdot \frac{1}{4i}
$$
so
$$
I=4\Re J+4\Im J
\\
\,\, =\Re e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}t\cdot \frac{1}{i}+\Im e^{\left( 2i-1 \right) t}t\cdot \frac{1}{i}
\\
\,\, =te^{-t}\left( \Re e^{2it}\frac{1}{i}+\Im e^{2it}\frac{1}{i} \right) 
\\
\,\, =te^{-t}\left( \Im e^{2it}-\Re e^{2it} \right) 
\\
\,\, =te^{-t}\left( \sin 2t-\cos 2t \right) 
$$
thus
$$
y_p=te^{-t}\left( \sin 2t-\cos 2t \right) 
$$
